# Merging Coordinate (long, lat) to a region(polygon)

Tags: qgis, merge, latitude-longitude

At present I have sports grant data, coded by longitude and latitude. This data is broken down by amount received, as well as the intended sport.

I also have various other data, broken down by electoral division (ED).

I would like to do the following. I would like to merge these individual longitude and latitude points into their respective electoral division (polygons). Thus I would know the particular ED grant recipient A was in, how much they received, what sport, along with all the relevant information about that particular ED (population, employment etc.).

Edit - As the image shows, I am running into some issues [image: QGIS image]

[image: crs]

Update 25/2/16 Images follow comments below

[image: ED]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use the **Join attributes by location** tool which combines attributes from your points layer to your polygon layer.

You can access this from the toolbar:

*Vector > Data Management Tools > Join attributes by location*

Set the parameters accordingly to obtain the full set of attributes for each polygon.

[image: Join attributes by location]

Comment: My grant data is in a csv file which has longitude and latitude coordinates for each grant. Is it possible to use this csv file to and lat/long data to place each grant recipient into their intended electoral division?

Comment: @SeanO'C - Yes, you can import your csv as points as described in [this tutorial](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/importing_spreadsheets_csv.html). Once imported (make sure both layers and your projection are using the same Coordinate Reference System, CRS), you can then run the _Join attributes by location_ tool.

Comment: Joesph - It appears I'm having some difficulty getting qgis to read my coordinates. I have attached an image for reference.

Comment: @SeanO'C - Try unchecking **DMS Coordinates** when importing, this is used for _degrees, minutes, seconds_ which your format is not.

Comment: Joseph - Unfortunately, I'm still running into issues. Would it be something related to my CSV file coordinates where obtained using a geo coding website which references Google maps and my shape file uses as different CRS? I've amended my original comment to highlight.

Comment: @SeanO'C - Is it the same issue that you cannot import your csv? I created a .csv file using the coordinates you have shown and was able to map them. Or have the points been imported but you cannot see them on top of your polygons?

Comment: Joseph -  I import the CSV and a specify the same CRS layer as I see when I click on the shape file. Yet all that occurs is a singular point is generated which lies outside the map. As you can see from the images above.

Comment: @SeanO'C - Not sure if you're aware but from the image of your csv, some points have the same coordinates which means they will overlap one another. Are you expecting to see points on top of your polygons? If so, this might be the case of **layer ordering**. In the **Layers** panel on the left, right-click on the name (or surrounding toolbar) and you should see a list of options. Enable the **Layer Ordering Panel**, it should come up as an extra tab underneath. There should be a _Control rendering order_ setting, enable this and your points should show (change the order if they don't).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36215/discussion-between-sean-oc-and-joseph).

Comment: You could post the first 10 entries of your csv in your question, that would help to check whether the CSV data has issues